# How to add quantity increment and decrement on category listing page and product page in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add quantity increment and decrements on category listing page and product detail page in magento 1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantity Box in the Category Products Listing Page in magento.

**list.phtml**

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>">
 <div class="quantity">
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getMinimalQty($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
</div>
<button class="form-button addToCart" onclick="productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>.submit()"></button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?> = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>');
     productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>.submit = function(){
     if (this.validator.validate()) {
             this.form.submit();
         }
     }.bind(productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>);
</script>
```

**custom.js**

```
<script>
jQuery("div.quantity").append('<input type="button" value="+" id="add1" class="plus" />').prepend('<input type="button" value="-" id="minus1" class="minus" />');
        jQuery(".plus").click(function()
        {
            var currentVal = parseInt(jQuery(this).prev(".qty").val());

            if (!currentVal || currentVal=="" || currentVal == "NaN") currentVal = 0;

            jQuery(this).prev(".qty").val(currentVal + 1);
        });

        jQuery(".minus").click(function()
        {
            var currentVal = parseInt(jQuery(this).next(".qty").val());
            if (currentVal == "NaN") currentVal = 0;
            if (currentVal > 0)
            {
                jQuery(this).next(".qty").val(currentVal - 1);
            }
        });
         </script>
```

Comment: Please approve my answer. If it is working properly. Thank you. :)

Comment: I have approved. 
but I have one more query - Can I use the same code on product page.

Comment: Yes. If you have any error, then please let me know.

Comment: I have put this in addtocart.phtml, but there is no change.

Comment: how can i achieve the same feature in products widget